# CSS Margin Minus Equal in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Is there a way in jQuery that we can do something like:

```
$('#element').css('margin-left',-=10);
```

The purpose is for propeties like Left, Right, Width, Height, Margins, Paddings,... Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. The syntax is just a little bit different.

```js
$('div').css('margin-left',"-=10px");
```

```css
div{margin: 40px; background: red; height: 20px; width: 20px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div></div>
```

Comment: It worked! Will accept the answer soon :) Thank you :D

Comment: @LanMai no probs ;)

Answer (score 0):

You're trying a shorthand (that I don't think exists) for a pretty straightforward application of an explicit getter:

```
const $element = $('#element');

$element.css('margin-left', $element.css('margin-left') - 10);
```

Comment: Not sure why the -1. It's actually what is done internally anyway.